# Decay rate for the probability of deviating from the mean for the sample mean

Tags: probability-theory, means, law-of-large-numbers

Let $X_1,X_2, \ldots$ be independent and identically distributed random variables, with finite mean $\mu$. No assumption is made on higher order moments: they may be finite or infinite. Then, the law of large numbers asserts that
$$
\textbf{(1)}   \qquad P\left(\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^b X_i - \mu\right|>\epsilon\right) \to 0, \quad n\to \infty, \quad \forall \epsilon>0.
$$
In fact, convergence of $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ to $\mu$ holds in a stronger form, i.e. with probability one, and this can be shown resorting to the first Borel-Cantelli lemma and a coupling argument for sums of truncated random variables, as done e.g. in

*Billingsley (1995) Probability and Measure, Third edition, Wiley, pp. 282--283.*

Yet, such arguments seem not to provide an explicit decay rate to $0$ for the probability on the left-hand side of $\textbf{(1)}$.

**QUESTION** Under the above general assumptions, is it possible to conclude that
$$
\textbf{(2)}   \qquad P\left(\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^b X_i - \mu\right|>\epsilon\right) = O(r_n), \quad n\to \infty, \quad \forall \epsilon>0.
$$
for some $r_n =O(1/\log n)$? Clearly, assuming that the $X_i$'s have a finite second moment, Chebychev's inequality immediately allows to claim that $r_n=1/n$, but what if no further assumption is made on higher order moments?

Comment: Probably a place to look for counterexamples is things like $f_\epsilon(x)=C_\epsilon x^{-2} \log(x)^{-1-\epsilon}$ on $[a,\infty)$, $a>1$. In principle you should expect extremely slow convergence in this regime. Alternately you could try looking at some of the heavy-tailed stationary distributions.